# How to add up all values in column F that has the same value in column A?

Tags: microsoft-excel

i.e. if I'd like to sum the total score of a student from a sheet like this:

```
Student ID | Score 
  123456   |   12
  654789   |   14
  585822   |   5
  982531   |   22
  982531   |   32
  123456   |   17
  654789   |   14
  585822   |   18
```

I'd like to get back

```
Student ID | Score
  123456   |   29
  654789   |   28
  585822   |   23
  982531   |   54
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do this by using `SUMIF(range,criteria,sum_range)`

You would need to create a list of distinct Student IDs which can be achieved with Advanced Filter (selecting 'Unique records only' and 'Copy to another place').

The formula would be `=sumif(A:A,A2,F:F)`

Comment: This is not a solution if you have 10,000 students

Comment: The number of students is really immaterial to this suggestion.  This would only be unusable if the number of students was changing frequently.

Comment: Depending on the use case either solution will work. If I had a fixed list of students and was adding scores through the year and reporting each period I would use a SUMIF table. If I wanted to do a one off piece of analysis I would stick to a pivot table.

Comment: What I understand is that I need to filter each student individually and then make the sum - "copy to another place". So if I have 10k students I will need to repeat this 10k times...

Comment: The advanced filter allow you to create a complete distinct list of all your Student_IDs details on how to do this is here: (http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/filter-for-unique-records-HP003073425.aspx?CTT=3)

Answer (score 5):

Another way to achieve the same result is to create a pivot table based on your data: select your data, choose Insert Pivot Table, Finish. Use the Student ID as the row field and Score as the Data field.

Comment: +1 good to see you here Thomas :)

Comment: I don't see this option in Excel2010

Comment: In the toolbar, go to the Insert tab, then click the PivotTable button (it's the first button on the left). See [Working with PivotTables in Excel](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/13336/working-with-pivottables-in-excel/) for a guide.

Comment: Impressively, Excel 365 successfully and quickly performed this on a dataset of 325,000 rows for me.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to use Excel but I thought this was an interesting problem so I tried to figure out. Here is how I got it to work. It might not be the best way to do it.

Click Insert -> PivotTable. It will auto select what it thinks should be in the table. You can also manually select the data that you want to have in the pivot table.

[image]

Check the check boxes that you want to include in your pivot table (Student ID and Score).

Drag the Student ID from the fields list to the Row Labels box.

In the values box, click the down arrow for "Sum of Student ID" and click Remove Field.

At the end it may look like this:
[image]

You can right click on Grand Total and remove it if you don't want a grand total of the students scores. You can also sort by student ID by clicking on the down arrow that appears when you select the cell with the title for your student ID's and choose one of the sorting options.

Thanks for the test data. It was fun to play with.